# How to bring in BQ Big Numeric comparision in SQL Queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to query the following in google BigQuery:

```
SELECT role FROM `<PROJECT>.<DATABASE>.<TABLE>` WHERE googleId = 109024200300000000000
```

Though this isn't working as I am getting this error:

`Invalid integer literal: 109024000000000000000 at [1:85]`

I am not sure how to tell BigQuery that this is a Big Numeric and not Integer.

One way I found is:

`` SELECT role FROM `<PROJECT>.<DATASET>.<TABLE>` WHERE googleId = CAST('109024002200000000000' as BIGNUMERIC) ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1; ``

but not sure if this would be the most efficient way.

Comment: you can use shorter version (without `CAST`) - `WHERE googleId = BIGNUMERIC '109024002200000000000'`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Mikhail Berlyant in the comment, you can use a shorter version (without CAST) as follows by including datatype ‘BIGNUMERIC’ along with the value.

```
SELECT role FROM `<PROJECT>.<DATABASE>.<TABLE>` WHERE googleId = BIGNUMERIC '109024002200000000000'
```